# Derivation of the BIC

Tags: self-study, bayesian, bic

i am trying to self-study / understand the derivation of the BIC. I have studied that:

[image]

however - it is not quite clear to me how this leads to the formula below. I don't fully understand where the log p(theta) comes from - i would expected the formula to be log(P|D)-1/2log|H|. Any help much appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Check this link, it has a detailed derivation.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/265739543_On_the_Derivation_of_the_Bayesian_Information_Criterion

Comment: it's shown in the definition section on wiki, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayesian_information_criterion